# WPF Bind Grid.Column Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, grid, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I need to set Grid.Column property of an item by a converter. 
this is my xaml :

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Periodo.Inizio}">
            <Grid.Column>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemColumnSetter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Timeline}" Path="StartDate" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Timeline}" Path="EndDate" />
                    <Binding Path="Periodo.Inizio" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Column>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

But don't work.
I'm sure that the converter work well...

Comment: You forgot to add the code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TextBlock will be wrapped in another control of some sort, that means any `Grid.XXX` properties will be disregarded. To apply those properly you need to do the binding in the `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`.

Should be something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemColumnSetter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Timeline}" Path="StartDate" />
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Timeline}" Path="EndDate" />
                    <Binding Path="Periodo.Inizio" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Did you use a setter like this? i.e. `<Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan"><Setter.Value>...` It should work, maybe there's a problem in your binding or converter?

Comment: ok, the problem was that the Math.Ceiling function return a double. now i convert it in a int32 and all works fine. thanks